# How to properly write a custom react hook which depends on a value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, window-resize

The goal of my hook is to determine the "open direction" of the menu.
When there is not enough height, the open direction will switch from "bottom" to "top".
I simplified my code to a dummy example to be able to demonstrate it.
You can see it in the animated gif I added.

So, what is my problem?
In my real code, the logic of the "open direction" **depends** on the last "openDirection" from the state.
With classes which I'm used to, it works well, I've added the code example using classes.
In the `handleResize` I'm writing to the console the current `openDirection`, to simulate the use of it in my real code.

**BUT** in my hooks code example, you can see that each time I am writing to the console from the `handleResize`, the `openDirection` **is always the first initial value of the state** which is bottom.

I guess it works this way because I'm giving the `[]` dependency, so `useLayoutEffect` works on the first time only. But what should I do? if I pass `openDirection` as a dependency, it will work, but then it means that each time `addEventListener` will be added and `removeEventListener` will be removed, for every resize event!

I'm really confused about it, what should I do?

```
import { useLayoutEffect, useState } from 'react';

const useOpenDirection = () => {
  const [openDirection, setOpenDirection] = useState("bottom");

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    const handleResize = () => {
      console.log('openDirection', openDirection);
      if (window.innerHeight < 622) {
        setOpenDirection("top");
      } else {
        setOpenDirection("bottom");
      }
    }

    window.addEventListener('resize', handleResize);
    return () => window.removeEventListener('resize', handleResize);
  }, []);

  return openDirection;
};

export default useOpenDirection;
```

The complete code for live editing:

[classes code example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/resize-with-classes?file=Test.js)

[hooks code example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/resize-with-hooks?file=Test.js)

[image]

Comment: You need to include the code in the body of the question itself (not an external link).

Comment: @coreyward thanks for the note, I edited the post, I hope it's more clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `openDirection`  has become a stale closure, because of empty array as dependencies. You can access current value of `openDirection` if you use functional update:

```
useLayoutEffect(() => {
    const handleResize = () => {

        setOpenDirection(current => {
            // If you need you can also use current to compute return value of this function
            if (window.innerHeight < 622) {
                console.log('openDirection', current);
                return "top";
            } else {
                console.log('openDirection', current);
                return "bottom";
            }

        });

    }

    window.addEventListener('resize', handleResize);
    return () => window.removeEventListener('resize', handleResize);
}, []);
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I've tried your code with the function, and the `console.log` still prints the initial `bottom` value, even when it becomes `top`.

Comment: @MosheKerbel isn't this what you want? https://ibb.co/GCDSXjs. It uses my code.

Comment: actually works like a charm! I really appreciate the help. I probably had a mistake while copying it, now it works great.